# Помогите добавить правильно асинхронную подгрузку тегов при сколе

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Пытаюсь добавить асинхронную подгрузку, но на данный момент она работает не правильно, при первом открытии списка отображается 15 тегов при прокрутке происходит скачек и подгружается еще 10, после закрытия списка и повторного открытия догружаются остальные теги, в чем может быть проблема? (сейчас с бека не приходит длина всех тегов, пока это захардкодил, зная длину 38)

```
data() {
  return {
   tags: [],
   options: [],
   loading: false,
   observer: null,
   offset: 0,
   totalTagsCount: 38,
   limit: 15,
    };



 },

  mounted() {
    this.observer = new IntersectionObserver(this.infiniteScroll);
    this.getTagsList();
  },


    filtered() {
     return this.options.filter((option) => option.id !== -1 && option.name.length <= 38);
    },


     paginated() {
      return this.filtered.slice(0, this.limit);
     },
    
    hasNextPage() {
      return this.options.length < this.totalTagsCount;
    },
 }
  methods: {
    async onOpen() {
      if (this.hasNextPage) {
        await this.$nextTick();
        this.observer.observe(this.$refs.load);
      }
    },

    onClose() {
      this.observer.disconnect();
    },

    async infiniteScroll([{ isIntersecting, target }]) {
     if (isIntersecting && this.hasNextPage) {
     const ul = target.offsetParent;
     const scrollTop = target.offsetParent.scrollTop;

    if (this.options.length < this.totalTagsCount) {
      await this.getTagsList();
      this.limit += 10;
    }

    await this.$nextTick();
    ul.scrollTop = scrollTop;
  }
},

    async setSelected(val){
      this.loading = true;
      this.tags = val;
    },

    async getTagsList(chatTags = null) {
     if (this.loading || this.options.length >= this.totalTagsCount) return;
     this.loading = true;
     const url = `путь`;
     const request = {
      search: '',
      limit: 15,
      offset: this.options.length,
     };

    try {
     const response = await axios.get(url, { params: request });
     const responseData = response.data.data;

    const newTags = responseData.tags || [];
    const filteredTags = newTags.filter(tag => tag.name.length <= 38);

    this.options = [...this.options, ...filteredTags];
    if (chatTags) this.tags = responseData.tags || [];
    return this.options;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  } finally {
    this.loading = false;
  }
},
```